# Ошибка в библиотеке pyspectator

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, pyspectator

Ошибка:

```
sharikfi@rsp-VM:~/Desktop/ResourceMonitoring$ /bin/python3 /home/sharikfi/Desktop/ResourceMonitoring/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sharikfi/Desktop/ResourceMonitoring/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pyspectator.computer import Computer
  File "/home/sharikfi/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyspectator/computer.py", line 5, in <module>
    from pyspectator.memory import NonvolatileMemory, VirtualMemory, SwapMemory
  File "/home/sharikfi/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyspectator/memory.py", line 5, in <module>
    from pyspectator.collection import LimitedTimeTable
  File "/home/sharikfi/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyspectator/collection.py", line 1, in <module>
    from collections import MutableMapping, Container
ImportError: cannot import name 'MutableMapping' from 'collections' (/usr/lib/python3.10/collections/__init__.py)
```

Код:

```
from pyspectator.computer import Computer

computer=Computer


Cpu = (Computer.processor.name)

print(Cpu)
```

Linux Ubuntu

Comment: Скорее всего не совпадает версия Python'а у вас и для которой написана библиотека.

Comment: в документации к данной библиотеке написанно 

Requirements

    Python version: 3.X

Comment: Судя по коду из репозитория этой библиотеки, она рассчитана не на 3.X, а на <=3.9. Попробуйте версии 3.9 или 3.8.